# CLOUDFRONT - Site host name, https://media.domainname.com, does not match your SSL certificate Subject Name

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I woke up this morning to an email from Google Webmaster Tools saying the following:

> We have noticed that the host name of your site, https://media.domainname.com,         does not match any of the "Subject Names" in your SSL certificate, which were:
>
> *.cloudfront.net
>
> cloudfront.net
>
> As a result, many web browsers will block users from accessing your site, or display a security warning message when your site is accessed.

This appears to be a cloudfront issue, but I cannot find any support from Amazon at all. Furthermore, site traffic according to Google Analytics is down about 40% out of nowhere.

Anyone have an idea what this means and what actions need to be taken? I am at a loss here.

Comment: Are you using cloudfront to serve SSL? It needs to be configured. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

Comment: Chances are you're not using media.domainname.com as HTTPS. It would've been causing issues from the beginning if you were.